# Android Java - How to embed online video

Tags: java, android, video, embed

I've looked around and want to know if i can embed and play videos like this within my the android app using default video player/webview or video view.

```
< script type = " text/javascript" src="http://URLHERE" > < / script >
```

I either want the app to play this video in the default video player or play it in the WebView inside the app.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use VideoView here in an example.

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
//Use a media controller so that you can scroll the video contents
//and also to pause, start the video.
MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this); 
mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videoUrl));
videoView.start();
```

Comment: I get a "Can't play this video" error. This is the URL: http://www.ilive.to/embed/38804

Answer (score 0):

you can use either [MediPlayer.setDataSource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource%28java.lang.String%29) or [VideoView.setVideoURI](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html#setVideoURI%28android.net.Uri%29) for this purpose.

If you want to play the online stream via android's mediaplayer the use `MediaPlayer` and if you wan to show the view within your application then use `VideoView`

Comment: This is the embed url: http://www.ilive.to/embed/38804
I tried the method below and it says "Can't play this video"

Comment: Use video src url and make sure you gave internet permission on manifest.

Comment: that's the problem, I can't find the source of the live stream. It's one of those javascript functions which "makes" or hides the url away from the viewers. Any other ideas?